# Can no longer change rate after scrubbing

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

Simple scenario: I want to seek to a certain position inside a video, and subsequently play it.

The problem is when I first use [`SetRate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [set the rate to 0 in order to enable scrubbing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee892370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I can no longer run the video afterwards. It seems as if I'm unable to change the rate from 0 to anything else. I can only do framestepping by calling [`Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When simply running the video (without setting rate to 0), subsequent rate changes do work. I also noticed if I set the rate to 0 and back again to a positive rate, without actually scrubbing in between (`Start()`), the rate change does happen!

Is there any extra work I have to do in order to exit 'scrubbing mode'?

Comment: Did you receive the `MESessionRateChanged` Event and the `MESessionScrubSampleComplete` Event?

Comment: @CPlusSharp I did receive the `MESessionRateChanged` event. I only call `Start()` after I received it. I'll verify whether I receive the `MESessionScrubSampleComplete` event after calling start, but I'm not expecting it since I just want to start playback.

Comment: @CPlusSharp A `MESessionScrubSampleComplete` event is still triggered when calling `Start()` after the rate has been set to one again, and the `MESessionRateChanged` event was received. So it does seem as if I'm still in scrubbing mode.

Comment: I called `GetRate()` after setting it, and it remains 0. No error code is returned when calling `SetRate()`

Comment: I [reported this as a bug on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763978/can-no-longer-change-rate-after-scrubbing-in-media-foundation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the rate between Forward/Zero when the session is playing. Scrubbing puts the session into the play state (since you called `Start()`), so after scrubbing you need to call `Pause()` or `Stop()` before you can set the rate back to normal.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696979(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I would expect I tried that, although can't recall/check it unfortunately. Also I reported [_"SetRate() returns no error code"_](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763978/can-no-longer-change-rate-after-scrubbing-in-media-foundation) in my bug report, which seemingly got accepted.

Comment: Also notice I receive the 'MESessionRateChanged' event.

Comment: There is likely a bug with MF thinking `SetRate()` succeeds when it doesn't - which could explain why 'MESessionRateChanged' gets fired. I just know that I recently ran into this problem and the fix was to call `Pause()` before resuming playback with `SetRate()` and `Start()`.

Comment: Cool! +1 for verifying that. Can't accept though unless I find the time to test it again. :/

Comment: I was having the same problem as @StevenJeuris and I can confirm that this answer solves it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Andreas. Marked as accepted!